# 8GB stick thinks it's a 4GB one

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a "SanDisk Cruzer USB Device" which is labelled for 8GB and always was 8GB. I didn't use it for a while and now it lists 3.49GB on my PC. I think I've done something to it a while ago, but can't remember what I was doing.

I've tried different PCs on that, with different OSs (Ubuntu Server 12, Ubuntu Desktop 10, Windows 7, Windows XP). They all listed the device for around 4GB. I also tried formatting but in the format dialog (of windows XP) I could only choose 3.50GB capacity (whether I'd select FAT32 or exFAT).

What might the problem be? How can I resolve this issue?

---

I ran `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` on Ubuntu and found:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3763 MB, 3763600896 bytes
116 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1022 cylinders, total 7350783 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x69686373

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   ?  4281232757  1652651905   833193222+  6d  Unknown
/dev/sdb2   ?  1141509631  1685422960   271956665   66  Unknown
/dev/sdb3   ?  1937007983  1937010555        1286+  65  Novell Netware 386
/dev/sdb4      2885681152  2885736393       27621    0  Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdX` on Ubuntu? (Replace `sdX` with the partition assigned to your USB flash drive.)

Comment: @jaume I added it to my question

Comment: I forget if removable disks are shown in the disk management software built into Windows.  It looks from this you have several Unknown paritions on the device.  Its entirely possible the device is just broken or is beyond its lifespan in writes ( flash drivers are design this way ).

Comment: @Ramhound that's a pity.. is there anyway to repartition the device to get the 8GB back? -- also, why the downvote?

Comment: Ubuntu reports 4 GB now... I think the USB drive is going haywire,  I'd recommend that you stop using it. I don't see how you can get your 8 GB back.

Comment: +1 because I don't think your question should be downvoted.

Comment: @jaume well thanks :-) I guess you can make this an answer and I'll accept it unless a solution comes up.

Comment: @CamilStaps - If the drive is just worn out then there is nothing you can do.  If they drive is damaged there is nothing that can be done.  If the drive is perfectly fine and you just messed around with the parition tables, not knowing what you did, I don't have a suggestion for you.  As for the downvote I have no idea....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the USB drive is going haywire, I'd recommend that you stop using it.

Ubuntu reports 4 instead of 8 GB:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 3763 MB, 3763600896 bytes
116 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1022 cylinders, total 7350783 sectors
(...)
```

And if you look at `fdisk`'s output more closely you will notice that the start and end sectors make no sense at all and don't match the total number of sectors on the Cruzer:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   ?  4281232757  1652651905   833193222+  6d  Unknown
/dev/sdb2   ?  1141509631  1685422960   271956665   66  Unknown
/dev/sdb3   ?  1937007983  1937010555        1286+  65  Novell Netware 386
/dev/sdb4      2885681152  2885736393       27621    0  Empty
```

Something's wrong with the USB flash drive. I don't see how you can get your 8 GB back.

Comment: I had this problem, but it was actually the _reader_ that was faulty, not the card.

Answer (score 0):

try to use " **HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool** " that can be downloaded from [cnet](http://download.cnet.com/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool/3000-2094_4-10974082.html) but if after quick format you have same issue try full format with that tool.

Comment: This tool is pretty much the same as Windows XP's tool and it didn't work. Thanks for the idea though and it might help others :-)

Comment: @Kaveh - Why wouldn't he just use the built-in disk manager within Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure, some flash does not partitioning but if this model support that it's a good idea

Comment: This lower-level format/init tool helped restore the full factory 8GB capacity to a USB stick, when the above naive high-level partition reformat kept it at only 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

Put the device in your windows machine and do the following:

1. On the start menu go to Run
2. In the box enter 'compmgmt.msc'
3. In the managment console select from the tree on the left 'Disk Managment'
4. On the right in the top list of disks, identify your flash drive and click the drive letter
5. That drive should now be focused in the list below.
6. I am assuming you are going to see a primary partition and a bunch of logical partitions
7. Delete the partitions until there is only one.
8. Format the only partition left.

This works in 85% of the problems with these drives I have seen. Occasionally someone will format one to be a boot device or a live linux distribution and there are a pile of inactive partitions for swap space and such.

As was mentioned in the comments, there is also a finite amount of writes for flash devices, but unless this was used as a primary os drive for a few years, I highly doubt you reached the write life on it.

I rarely suggest third party tools, however I have used [this partition wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) a few times to fix stubborn partition issues. It is fairly intuitive and easy to use.

Finally a warning: If you are not sure which drive you need to fix the partitions on, or you are at all confused about the drive letter, stop before you start. You can seriously wreck a machine if you mess with the partitions on the wrong disk.

Comment: I made all partitions one on linux, but the total size is 3,50GB, unfortunately.

Comment: when you view it in windows does it show any un-allocated space?

Comment: No <!-- random text to get the minimum //-->

Comment: I guess it is just a bad drive.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on Ubuntu 14.04; it didn't work. On Windows 7 Pro (other win OSs should be fine as well), the following worked for me.

Run diskpart (press Win+R and type "diskpart" without quotation mark).

```
list disk
```

Availabe disks are listed as disk 0, disk 1 and so on. Looking at size of disks, determine which disk is the USB stick. Suppose it's disk 1. Now run these commands:

```
select disk 1
list partition
clean
list partition
create partition primary
list partition
format fs=fat32 quick
list partition
exit
```